# Rails 3: Remap user_path route with match rule

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have got this in my routes file:

```
resources :users

match '/@:id' => 'users#show'
```

When I go to `/@radeks` then it would be the same as if I would go to `/users/radeks`. However, I use `user_path` in my views, but this points to `/users/radeks` which I don't want.

How can I make `user_path` always point to `/@:id`?

---

### Edit

I also have got this in my User model:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match '/@:id' => 'users#show', :as => 'user'
```

The :as argument makes this a "named route". See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes for more info.

NB that you're overriding the default 'user' named route you get automagically from 'resources :users'